# symbol lookup error on a command

Tags: c

i'm trying to do some code in a keyboard driver, a 3rd party software that looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/NW1fH7e2) can run the command i'm trying to do in a plugin file that compiles alongside the daemon that the command needs to be sent to. the command looks like this.

```
g15_send_cmd (g15screen_fd,G15DAEMON_MKEYLEDS,mled_state);
```

[here's](http://pastebin.com/Kkdi2HUH) the code i'm working with and trying to run the command in (it compiles as a plugin with the daemon. in the uncompiled source it's

"g15daemon/plugin/g15_plugin_uinput.c"

the file that defines the command is in
(link)
["g15daemon/libg15daemon_client/g15daemon_clinet.h"](http://pastebin.com/ctB20e6x)

whereas with the g15macro (3rd software) is run from outside the daemon for various reasons i don't want to (and pretty much can't) use it, one being speed of execution of commands when keys are pressed.

so the program compiles like this without error it seems. but if the code i specified above activates, the driver(daemon) crashes giving

> g15daemon: symbol lookup error:
> /usr/lib/g15daemon/1.9.5.3/plugins/g15plugin_uinput.so: undefined
> symbol: g15_send_cmd

what did i do wrong or what am i missing here? (and i'm sorry if the code in the plugin file is ugly down by that switch command, but i didn't know how to do any better since i don't know C much at all, all i have behind me are Py and C#)

**Edit: the solution was given**

but i don't know how to add a linker flag, also since it links to a part of the program being compiled will it even work?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to link your plugin with `g15daemon_client` library. The simple way to fix it is to add `-lg15daemon_client` to the linker flags.

Comment: you mean this #include <g15daemon_client.h>?
its at line 44

Comment: @Rabcor: No, the include only declares a function (i.e. letting compiler know it exists somewhere). But the actual binary code lives in a library which you should link with.

Comment: ah i get it i think, how can i find out which library though? i thought i included everything that g15macro.c did that was related.

Comment: @Rabcor: I have just told you which library. If you mean a general case, you have to read documentation of the API you use, it tells what libraries you have to link with (if any).

Comment: Allright i figured that much out, but my problem is that libg15daemon_client.la doesn't exist yet, since it's a part of the program i'm compiling.